# Django Channels - Internal Custom Routing not working

Tags: python, django, websocket, channel, django-channels

I'm building a chat application based on this example (https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/blob/master/multichat/chat/routing.py).
When the javascript runs (socket already open, **ws_connect** has already been executed) it sends the JSON to over the websocket. This **'message'** is routed to **ws_receive** which then loads the JSON into a 'payload' variable. The 'message' **reply_channel** is added to the payload variable (dict). Using the Channels command, the payload is then sent and routed to **chat_join**, where it should simply execute the hardcoded message.reply_channel.send.

All steps up until

```
payload['reply_channel'] = message.content['reply_channel']
```

work fine. But then the payload is not being routed to the **chat_join** consumer. If it is being routed correctly, then the reply_channel value is not being read properly, due to which the message is not being sent back to the client.

**Can't seem to find the breaking point here. Need help fixing this code.**

**.js**

```
//Join Room
socket.send(JSON.stringify({
    "command": "join",
    "room": "102"
}));
```

**routing.py**

```
from channels.routing import route
from MyProject.consumers import ws_connect, ws_receive, chat_join

websocket_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_connect),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive),    
]

custom_routing = [
    route("chat.receive", chat_join, command=r'^join$'),
]
```

**consumers.py**

```
from channels import Channel
def ws_receive(message):
    payload = json.loads(message['text'])
    payload['reply_channel'] = message.content['reply_channel']
    Channel("chat.receive").send(payload)

def chat_join(message):
    message.reply_channel.send({
        "text": json.dumps({
            "alpha": "1",
            "beta": "2",
        }),
    })
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Nothing happens when clicking the room name button.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript file should be sending the data with a `"text"` key.

Source: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asgi.html#send-close

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change my routing.py to as given below. I included the custom routing as normal routes in the websocket_routing and it started working for me. Hope this helps.

```
websocket_routing = [
    # Called when WebSockets connect
    route("websocket.connect", ws_connect),

    # Called when WebSockets get sent a data frame
    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive), 

    # Called when WebSockets disconnect
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),    


    #Custom Routing
    #Join Chat
    route("chat.receive", chat_join, command=r'^join$'),
    route("chat.receive", chat_send, command=r'^send$'),
]
```